# WooCommerce theming and Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

When I began theming for WooCommerce, I copied over the files from plugin to build of of those files that already exist. The problem however, is I realized that my theme doesn't have javascript enabled, even though I didn't change the classes or id's.

For instance, the tax is supposed to update on the checkout page as the user writes in their shipping address. Was there something I missed or have to add to enable javascript in my theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable jQuery on the front-end, your theme will need to load that. A slightly modified example taken from the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

```
function so_26446385_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_26446385_scripts_method' );
```

Also, your theme needs to follow basic theme standards and include [`wp_head()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) and [`wp_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer). Without these scripts will also not be loaded in the appropriate places.

Impossible to say if those are your only 2 problems, but that's where I would suggest you start.

Comment: jQuery isn't needed to get woocommerce to work, especially because I have been using it without jQuery.

Comment: That might be, but it works a lot better *with* javascript. And you did ask how to enable JS.

Comment: Yes yes, just correcting how it was said. 

I did try to get it to enable some of the JS functions within woocommerce, but no dice!

Comment: Fair enough. I know there is a lot of of scripting in WooCommerce so I assumed it was required. I would check your source to make sure scripts are, in fact, loading. And then I would check your browser's dev console to see errors. If you have a live site I would take a quick look.

Comment: I do: www.ontrgt.net

Comment: Javascript != jquery for the same reason openssl != C or Swing != Java.

Comment: Have you looked at my recommendations regarding `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`? Judging from your site's markup, you almost assuredly do *not* have these. There are zero WooCommerce (or any other plugin scripts) being loaded. I would also recommend that you not load jQuery from your theme. Load it from WordPress core as I have shown in my answer.

Comment: AH! There is a code that loads plugin scripts?

Comment: `wp_print_scripts()` and `wp_print_footer_scripts()` are run during `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` respectively. So without `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` (which are standard and expected to be in every theme) a lot of plugins will not function properly. Those are the big ones but do check out the [Theme Guidelines](https://make.wordpress.org/docs/theme-developer-handbook/part-four-releasing-your-theme/theme-review-guidelines/#required-hooks-and-navigation)